# Python pointer address to an uint_64 in a packed struct using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, pointers, ioctl

I am attempting to have a full "python only"* implementation of a particular ioctl.

This involves creating a packed struct. The C-Equivalent structure does not have typed pointers but rather stores pointer addresses as unsigned 64 bit integers. The buffer pointed to by these addresses will store the return data from the call. At the moment, I am struggling to get the packed structure to build correctly.

As a non-working example

```
ret_buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(4096)
struct.pack("I", ctypes.POINTER(ret_buf))
```

This complains that the argument is not an integer. Variations using by reference, c_char_p, etc also do not work.

Is there a way to get the address returned as an integer? Or similarly a series of casts that might work?

*I'm aware we could do this with C-Bindings and some wrappers there, but if possible we'd like to keep things as much in python as we can for simplifying our build and integration process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps use [`addressof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.addressof) which

> Returns the address of the memory buffer as integer.

Comment: Argh, hidden in plain sight in the ctypes doc. my bad. At the very least another step forward. Thanks!